# How do I install the drivers for the Dell MFP 3115c printer?

Tags: windows, printer

I've been looking for hours on how to install the drivers for this Dell MFP 3115c printer.

I don't have the CD, so I had to look for the drivers online. I found them, but all it gives me is a folder full of file extensions that neither I nor my computer have anything to do with. There are no applications to execute, no images to mount, just a bunch of files with extensions that even almost no one on the internet knows about.

I tried following [Dell's Help instructions](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&docid=266471&l=en&s=gen).

Those instructions are all right up until step 17; a "new window" never appears and therefore I can't continue the installation. What am I supposed to do?

The [documentation for the driver is here](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R257783&SystemID=PRN_LSR_3115CN&servicetag=&os=W732&osl=en&deviceid=9820&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=40&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=378797).

I'm using Windows 7 32 Bit, which is supported, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [driver](https://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R257783&SystemID=PRN_LSR_3115CN&servicetag=&os=W732&osl=en&deviceid=9820&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=40&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=378797) (which you have done)
2. Extract driver by double clicking the EXE (I suggest keep the default extraction path as I reference it later)
3. Open "devices and printers" from the start menu
4. Go to Add Printer (not add device) and select "add a local printer"
5. Now this next step depends on how you have it hooked up. If USB select "use an existing port" then find the USB virtual port you will be using in the list. If via IP: select create new port then Standard TCP/IP and click next, finally type in the IP of the printer and click next.
6. Select "Have disk" on the next window and then click browse in the subsequent popup window. Now you want to navigate to C:\dell\drivers\R257783\Print\Win_x32\PCL you will see a file that you can select called dlxbazi.inf. Select this file and click open then click ok on the pop up, finally click next.
7. The last few options are personal preferences (default, print test page, share printer Ect.)

Your new printer should be installed and working properly now.